# How can i detect what color a mouse pointer is over in JavaScript in order to reset a game?

Tags: javascript, html, colors, mouseevent, mouse

I am currently creating a cursor-maze game where the objective is to traverse through a randomly generated maze with your cursor, if the user touches the randomly generated walls (Trying to identify by color) then the user is reset.

I have been searching endlessly for a way to detect if my mouse pointer is over a specified color because initiating each wall as a shape and detecting coordinates is a much more complicated task since the maze is randomly generated. Ive seen some postings saying use the onmouseover event in HTML however ive only seen it used in detecting a button or text element, not a color. Is what I am trying to do even possible, and if not what could be a good workaround?

here is my current code:

```
let maze = null;
let res = 50;
let mazeSizes = [25,50];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 450);
  
  noStroke();
  
  makeMaze(width/res + 2, height/res + 2);
  
  drawMaze();
}

let count = 0;
function draw() {
  fill("#39A7FF");
  ellipse(775, 425, 20, 20);
  if(count % 0.5 == 0) {
    if(maze.stack.length != 0) {
      background("#68c7ff");
      mazeIterate();
      drawMaze();
    }
  }
  count++;
}

function makeMaze(w, h) {
  maze = 
  {
    "stack":[],
    "tiles":[],
    "w":w,
    "h":h
  };
  
  for(let i = 0; i < w; i++) {
    maze.tiles[i] = [];
    for(let j = 0; j < h; j++) {
      maze.tiles[i][j] = 
      {
        "up":"wall",
        "down":"wall",
        "left":"wall",
        "right":"wall",
        "isStart":false,
        "isCurrent":false,
        "x":i,
        "y":j,
        "seen":false
      }
      if(i == 0 || i == w-1 || j == 0 || j == h-1) {
        maze.tiles[i][j].seen = true;
      }
    }
  }
  
  maze.tiles[1][1].isCurrent = true;
  maze.tiles[1][1].isStart = true;
  maze.tiles[1][1].seen = true;
  maze.stack.push(maze.tiles[1][1]);
}

function mazeIterate() {
  let current = maze.stack.pop();
  
  let tileAndWall = pickNeighbor(current);
  if(tileAndWall) {
    maze.stack.push(current);
    tileAndWall.tile[tileAndWall.wall] = "open";
    current[opositeWall(
      tileAndWall.wall)] = "open";
    tileAndWall.tile.seen = true;
    maze.stack.push(tileAndWall.tile);
    
    current.isCurrent = false;
    tileAndWall.tile.isCurrent = true;
  }
  else if(maze.stack.length != 0) {
    current.isCurrent = false;
    maze.stack[
      maze.stack.length-1].isCurrent = true;
  }
}

function pickNeighbor(tile) {
  let unSeen = [];
  
  let upTile = maze.tiles[tile.x][tile.y+1];
  if(!upTile.seen) {
    unSeen.push({
      "tile":upTile,
      "wall":"up"
    });
  }

  let downTile = maze.tiles[tile.x][tile.y-1];
  if(!downTile.seen) {
    unSeen.push({
      "tile":downTile,
      "wall":"down"
    });
  }

  let rightTile = maze.tiles[tile.x+1][tile.y];
  if(!rightTile.seen) {
    unSeen.push({
      "tile":rightTile,
      "wall":"right"
    });
  }

  let leftTile = maze.tiles[tile.x-1][tile.y];
  if(!leftTile.seen) {
    unSeen.push({
      "tile":leftTile,
      "wall":"left"
    });
  }
  
  if(unSeen.length == 0) {
    return null;
  }
  
  return unSeen[Math.floor(
    Math.random()*unSeen.length
  )];
}

function opositeWall(wall) {
  if(wall == "up") {
    return "down"
  }
  else if(wall == "down") {
    return "up"
  }
  else if(wall == "right") {
    return "left"
  }
  else if(wall == "left") {
    return "right"
  }
  
  return -1;
}

function drawMaze() {
  push();
  translate(-res, -res);
  for(let i = 0; i < maze.tiles.length; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < maze.tiles[i].length; j++) {
      let tile = maze.tiles[i][j];
      drawTile(tile, i, j);
    }
  }
  pop();
}

function drawTile(tile, i, j) {
  strokeWeight(0);
  
  if(tile.seen == true) {
    fill("#24698e");
    square(i*res, j*res, res);
    
    strokeWeight(2);
    stroke("#c4ecff");
    if(tile.up == "wall") {
      line((i)*res, (j)*res, 
           (i+1)*res, (j)*res);
    }
    if(tile.down == "wall") {
      line((i)*res, (j+1)*res, 
           (i+1)*res, (j+1)*res);
    }
    if(tile.left == "wall") {
      line((i+1)*res, (j)*res, 
           (i+1)*res, (j+1)*res);
    }
    if(tile.right == "wall") {
      line((i)*res, (j)*res, 
           (i)*res, (j+1)*res);
    }
  }
  
  if(tile.isCurrent) {
    fill("#00faff")
    noStroke();
    circle(i*res + res/2, 
             j*res + res/2, res/3);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, how are you rendering the game? On an html canvas or so?

Comment: Hello! Would you be able to provide some code for what you are working on? Getting to see what you currently have in the works would allow people to help you better.

Comment: @juliushuck I am quite new to programming itself so I'm not sure what HTML canvas is, but I am currently working on p5.js web editor as well as Visual Studio Code p5js projects. Im only using HTML because that is the closest thing to answer for my problem that I have come across.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the get function: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/get

Should work like this:

```js
function draw() {
  checkMouseWallCollision();
}

function checkMouseWallCollision() {
  let colorAtMouse = get(mouseX, mouseY);
  if (isWallColor(colorAtMouse)) {
    // The users mouse is over a wall
  }
}

function isWallColor(color) {
  let wallColor = color("#c4ecff");
  return wallColor.equals(color);
}
```